# Discrete Mathmatics (tautology proof w/ logical equivalents)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-verification

So I'm proving a tautology with logical equivalents, but as I get to the end I'm not getting a truth. The question states 'Prove that each statement is a tautology' which leads me to believe that the statement is in fact true. Was wondering if anyone could take a look at my work and tell me if they spot any errors? I've tried a couple different ways, but this is the closest I've been able to get.

STATEMENT: [(p v q) ^ (p -> r) ^ (q -> r)] -> r

L.E.1    : [(p v q) ^ **('p v q)** ^ **('q v r)**] -> r ////**implication**

L.E.2: **'**[(p v q ) ^ ('p v q) ^ ('q v r)] **v r**   /////**implication**

L.E.3: [**'**(p v q) **v '**('p v q) **v '**('q v r)] v r ///// **demorgans**

L.E.4: [(**'p ^ q**) v (**p ^ q**) v (**q ^ r**)] v r/////**demorgans**

L.E.5: [('p ^ q) v (**q ^ p**) v (**q ^ r**)] v r//////**communicative**

L.E.6: [('p ^ q) v **q ^ (p v r)**] v r///////////**distributive**

L.E.7: [(**q ^ 'p**) v (q ^ (p v r)] v r///////////**communicative**

L.E.8: [(**q ^ ('p v (p v r)**)] v r/////////////**distributive**

L.E.9: [(q ^ (**('p v p)** v r)] v r//////////////**distributive**

L.E.10: [q ^ (**T v r**) ] v r //////////////////**complement**

L.E.11: [**q ^ T**] v r ///////////////////////**identity**

L.E.12: **q v r**  //final form.

As you can see, I am unable to get it to evaluate to true, but merely 'q v r'

Comment: Your second application of De Morgan's law is wrong.

Comment: L.E.1 has a typo: a $q$ instead of an $r$.

Comment: You can use `&emsp;` or `$\quad$` to create spaces. Also, please learn LaTeX to post on this site. Google StackExchange MathJax guide if you didn't see it in the instructions when you posted your question.

Comment: I was wondering how to format. Thank you for this information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> STATEMENT: [(p v q) ^ (p -> r) ^ (q -> r)] -> r
>
> L.E.1 : [(p v q) ^ ('p v $\color{red}{q}$) ^ ('q v r)] -> r
>   $\color{red}{\ Typo: should\ be\ r\ not\ q}$
>
> L.E.2: '[(p v q ) ^ ('p v q) ^ ('q v r)] v r
>
> L.E.3: ['(p v q) v '('p v q) v '('q v r)] v r
>
> L.E.4: [('p ^ $\color{red}{q}$) v (p ^ $\color{red}{q}$) v (q ^
>   $\color{red}{r}$)] v r$\color{red}{\ Forgot\ to\ negate\ second\ 
> variable\ in\ the\ brackets\ when\ using\ demorgans}$
>
> . . .
>
> L.E.12: q v r //final form.

Apart from those mistakes the rest is ok (except of the course the final answer).

This is what I obtained when expanding your statement:

[(p + q) ^ (p -> r) ^ (q -> r)] -> r

$\bar p\bar q$+p$\bar r$+q$\bar r$+r

$\bar p\bar q$+$\bar r$[p+q] +r

Let X=[p+q]

$\bar p\bar q$+$\bar r$X +r

$\bar p\bar q$+$\bar r$X +rX+r$\bar X$

$\bar p\bar q$+X(1)+r$\bar X$

But as X=[p+q] $\bar X=\bar p\bar q$ so

$\bar p\bar q$+[p+q]+r$\bar p\bar q$

$\bar p\bar q$(1+r)+[p+q]

p+q+$\bar p\bar q$

Which is a Tautology

Comment: I figured it out, but this is correct nonetheless so I'll give you the credit.